# Is putting conditional "debug mode" (if\else) blocks in production code bad practice - PHP

Tags: php, validation, debugging

I'm writing some classes for a personal project that handles data and ensures it conforms to my exact specifications.  The output is an array (JSON object for API) consisting of true\false values for the respective fields to see if they passed my tests.

Some of the tests are complex with multiple conditions and it is hard determine at face value why a field failed the tests.

For each of the tests I was thinking of putting a DEBUG flag which can be enabled at object instantiation.  That leaves me with two choices.

A) Copy the validate function as follows.  Within the debug_validate() function I return an additional array with the fields and the reason they failed.  This requires me to maintain two copies of the function.

```
if ($this->debug_mode) {
    debug_validate();
}else{
   validate();
}
```

B) Within the actual validate function I can do the following

```
if (!test1($field)) {
    $validation_result[$field]=false;
    if($this->debug_mode) {
       $debug_result[$field]="Field is too small. Result of strlen: ".strlen($field);
    }
}
.
.
.
```

This means that I have to run the "if" blocks every time the validation function runs even though it will not be used 99.9999999% of the time.  It seems inefficient.

Am I overthinking this.  I mean with modern hardware who cares if it runs an extra if statement.  I just wonder if in production this actually matters when it comes to millions of requests (have to think big :)) and these debug statements start to add up (few MS here, few MS there)

Comment: you might want to present your code on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ and look for feedback there.  questions like this are  [off topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on SO

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well if you were writing this for a company, then yes it would be a bad practice. The team would kick back the code to you during a code review & have you remove the debugging code.

Since you're developing a *personal project*, then you can use debugging code for now. The benefit is that it will help you debug the project faster, than without it. You can clean the code up later on, when you bake it for it's final production release. Or if you're switching from a `beta` to `gold` status in a future release (say 6 months or 1 year from now).

The hard part is seeing what's going on with a server, where you don't have direct access to the source code. That's usually what occurs on a QA, test, staging or production server. You can easily edit the code on your localhost box, but you won't be able to easily edit it on those other servers.

What you don't want to do is leave this open, without writing a way to securely protect it. You don't want others to be able to trigger this code... `if ($this->debug_mode) {`. If you put something important inside of that PHP block... like SQL... then someone can see it & start to understand how your database is laid out. It'll give them a clue as to where to go, to start hacking into your database. They'll want to start elevating their user access privileges! You don't want them to make themselves an administrator & lock you out of your own database! So make sure that you secure your code with something like this:

```
if (($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] === 'qa.yoursite.com') && ($this->debug_mode)) {
    debug_validate(); // <- QA uses this.
} else {
   validate(); // <- Production uses this.
}
```

Note: That only runs on a QA server, but it runs for everyone who can use that server! So be careful that you don't give access to the QA server to anyone else but yourself!

If you have a password protected login with a userId, then you can use this example. It will work on any server. You can also combine these 2 code examples to lock a userId to a specific server.

```
if ($myUserId === 'myUserId') {
   debug_validate(); // <- You'll use this.
} else {
   validate(); // <- Everyone else uses this.
}
```

Ideally, what you want to do is to only use the `validate();` code without the `debug_validate();` code and setup a unit test to run against your code. It should include tests to verify that everything validates correctly. It should also include tests to verify that bad data won't validate. When your site gets to that level, then you won't need to use the `debug_validate()` method anymore. The unit tests will report if everything is good or if anything fails.

I wouldn't worry about the `ms` load time at this point. Nor the server load. The PHP code will run so fast that you won't notice it. Focus more on getting the code to work properly, than making it look pretty. You can always refactor the code later to clean it up once it's working. It'll make you feel happier when you see the working code getting cleaner!

Comment: The purpose of me writing a "framework" for this is so that I don't have to put manual debug statements every time.  If I need to debug I simply set the debug flag to 1 and all of the debug statements will run.  If I have a debug_validate() function that means I have to duplicate the entirety of the validate() function.  Is this the "standard" practice?

Comment: No. It's a useful purpose, as the `debug=1` flag is convenient to use. It's not a standard practice in a team environment. It's a quick & dirty way to test personal projects. You may want to explore writing unit tests to avoid having to build this framework. Duplicating the entire `validate()` function is a bad idea. It sounds like it needs to be reworked, as it should return a true/false if the validation passes/fails. If you do use the `debug_validate()`, then I highly recommend protecting that framework idea, so that someone can't trigger it on the production server! Just be safe with it.

Comment: what about the practice of putting my debug statements between /* !! DEBUG START */ /* !! DEBUG END */  That way I can have my deployment toolset strip the debug statements prior to shipping it to a QA\staging.  This is a personal project but I want to be able to use it in a prod environment one day

Comment: Yes, you can put comments into your code like that. Most devOps build processes will strip /* comments */, when they create the production bundles of minified & concatenated code.

Answer (score -1):

Your production code would have to evaluate an extra "IF" conditional in either case, unless I am misunderstanding? Whether it lies within the function, or within the calling script, the additional overhead (which will likely be extremely minimal even under load, unless you have thousands of them) would be the same either way.

I have had production code with "Debug Mode" type flags in the past and it has worked fine - however, there are some problems with that approach - namely, you need to change code (i.e. toggle the flag on or off) and therefore do another build / deployment in order to debug. Also, remembering to turn on / off debug mode can be a chore. And it tends to dirty up your code / make it less readable / easily maintainable.

Personally, I would take a little bit different approach, especially if you think debugging will be a common thing for your app - You could write separate unit tests to do debugging, using a tool like PHP Unit. If you are logging incoming requests to your application in some shape or form, it should be easy to pipe production data over to your unit test code base and conduct your debugging in that environment, instead of in your production code.

If you are running a test driven development environment, writing unit tests first should be common practice anyway.

Comment: The scenario in "A" has less ifs than in "B".  but A requires me to duplicate code.  In B I have to run an if for every single test every single time.  For A I only have to run the if once but it requires me to duplicate the function